# scripts of type [inline], operation [update] and lang [groovy] are disabled

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-2.0

We have **elasticSearch** version 2.4.0. I have updated **elasticsearch.yml** with the following values:

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
script.update: true
script.mapping: true
script.engine.groovy.file.aggs: true
script.engine.groovy.file.mapping: true
script.engine.groovy.file.search: true
script.engine.groovy.file.update: true
script.engine.groovy.file.plugin: true
script.engine.groovy.indexed.aggs: true
script.engine.groovy.indexed.mapping: true
script.engine.groovy.indexed.search: true
script.engine.groovy.indexed.update: true
script.engine.groovy.indexed.plugin: true
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: true
script.engine.groovy.inline.mapping: true
script.engine.groovy.inline.search: true
script.engine.groovy.inline.update: true
script.engine.groovy.inline.plugin: true
```

I am using `_update_by_query` API with the following example payload:

```
{
  "script":{
  "inline": "ctx._source.myVariable = ctx._source.id == params.newVal ? 'test':ctx._source.myVariable ",
  "params": {
      "newVal": "2c9ef"
    }}
}
```

I am still getting the following error response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "scripts of type [inline], operation [update] and lang [groovy] are disabled"
            }
        ],
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "scripts of type [inline], operation [update] and lang [groovy] are disabled"
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

I have taken config details from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-scripting.html).

Answer (score 0):

You must restart your ES instance for these changes to take effect